# WebSocket socketo.me Error 400 , why?

Tags: php, websocket

http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

I testing (good work):

> Running It ¶ Complete, let's run it and test it. Open up three
>   terminal windows, typing:
>
> $ php bin/chat-server.php
>
> $ telnet localhost 8080
>
> $ telnet localhost
>
> 8080 In each of the telnet windows, type a message ("Hello World!")
>   and see it appear in the other!

---

I try (not working)

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

**WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400**

Why not worked?